# How to build a Request AWS .net

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I want to use `CostExplorer` to get the usage report to know information about consumption of services.
To do that I am creating a `AmazonCostExplorerClient` object and using the `GetCostAndUsage` method.
To use this I need to have a `GetCostAndUsageRequest` object and use it to get the intel I want but I don't understand how to fill in the properties of this type... 
How should I do it?

```
        GetCostAndUsageRequest request = new GetCostAndUsageRequest();

        request.Granularity = "DAILY";
        request.Metrics.Add("UsageQuantity");
        var gpDef = new GroupDefinition();
        gpDef.Key = "USAGE_TYPE";
        request.GroupBy.Add(gpDef);



        try
        {
            var response = client.GetCostAndUsage(request);
            //client is a AmazonCostExplorerClient object
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CostExplorer/TGetCostAndUsageRequest.html`

Comment: And post the code snippet of what have you tried yet.

Comment: Not sure. This is the current error I am getting :
-  'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature'